# Solving coupled first-order autonomous differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, physics, simulation

I am trying to run a simulation of a circuit to observe chaotic behavior, and have obtained a set of differential equations from an analysis of the circuit.

I thought perhaps I could produce a plot of the current `j[t]` or generate a parametric plot of `j[t]` and the voltage `V[t]`. My constants and used functions I used were

```
A=1;
ϕ=0.0257275275;
ω=151.6*10^3;
Cj=17*10^(-9);
Cs=35*10^(-9);
Rt=223.9;
I0=5*10^-6;
L=15*10^-3;
V0[t_]:=A*Cos[ω*t];
Id[x_]:=I0*(Exp[x/ϕ]-1);
Cd[x_] := Piecewise[
   {{Cj/Sqrt[1 - x/ϕ], x < 0},
    {Cs*Exp[x/ϕ], x >= 0}}
   ];
```

and the differential equations and input I used were,

```
eqn = {V'[t] == (j[t] - Id[V[t]])/Cd[V[t]], j'[t] == (V0[t] - Rt*j[t] - V[t])/L};
bc = {V[0] == A, j[0] == 0, θ[0] == 0};
pl = NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, j, {t, 0, 1}]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[j[t] /. pl], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

It would appear however that my method of evaluation is inappropriate as I'm getting an error from NDSolve: `The method currently implemented for delay differential equations does not support delays that depend directly on the time variable or dependent variables.` (**Resolved**)

Is there anyway I can resolve this or perhaps another way to solve the set of differential equations?

**Edit:** Removed unnecessary  third diff. eq. θ'[t]=ω. Unfortunately, it seems to be unable to solve an ordinary differential equation. A research paper on a similar circuit said that the equations could be solved numerically by an explicit fourth-order Runge-Kutta algorithm, so perhaps there's a way I can instruct Mathematica to solve it using this?

**Edit 2:** Removed`Cj/Sqrt[1 - x/ϕ]` from `x≥0` for `Cd`

Comment: There's an easy closed form for `θ[t]`; why not help `NDSolve[]` out and simplify your DEs?

Comment: @J.M. That was an easy fix, thanks. Now it seems to be having an issue solving the autonomous equations. I've added an approach used in the past from a paper I found in Edit.

Comment: Copying and paste 2D input doesn't always work well (e.g. the piecewise function).  It's better to copy-paste `InputForm` and to check by copying the SE code back into *Mathematica* and testing it.  I edited your Q to fix it, but I had to assume what the piecewise was meant to be.  Please check it.

Comment: The difficulty is probably the term `V[ω*t]`, which will require the value of `V` to be known far in advance of the current time `t`, in order to compute the value for `j'[t]`; further the difference is not fixed, but varies, which is what the error is complaining about.  Are you certain about the `V[ω*t]` term?

Comment: @MichaelE2. Yes, that is the correct piecewise function. V[ω*t] is a mistake indeed. It should have been the V0 function. I corrected it, but still getting the same error.

Comment: You need to remove the `θ[0] == 0` from `bc` to get rid of the `NDSolve::ndode` error.  Then I get an overflow error. :/  -- Your initial condition for `V[0]` implies `Cd[V[t]]` will have a nonzero imaginary part.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @MichaelE2. I should not be getting an imaginary part. I've removed `Cj` from `Cd` and cleaned it up further. The only remaining issue is a `1/0` infinite expression. `Cd[x]` should always be positive, so I'm still missing something that I haven't caught yet.

Comment: @MichaelE2. I believe the imaginary issue has been resolved. The contribution from the junction capacitance `Cj` is very small under a forward bias `V>0` so I removed it, since my approximation was no longer valid.

Comment: This can help:[link1](http://www.star.le.ac.uk/zrw/fractals/fractals.pdf) and [link2](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~chua/papers/Thamilmaran02.pdf)

Comment: @Mariusz. Both only mention that they used a 4th-order Runge-Kutta algorithm to simulate the circuits. Mathematica should be able to use this method either by inspection or when told explicitly. I'll try to simulate the similar circuit in the second link and see what I learn.

Comment: I've reported the "DiscontinuityProcessing" issue to Wolfram Support. In a couple of days, we'll see if they think it's a bug. -- The techie at WRI called it an "issue", but I'll take bug as read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After removing the superfluous `θ[0] == 0` from `bc`, the key to the solution is a subtle change in the use of `Piecewise` in the definition of `Cd`:

```
Cd[x_] := Piecewise[{{Cj/Sqrt[1 - x/ϕ], x < 0}}, Cs*Exp[x/ϕ]]

eqn = {V'[t] == (j[t] - Id[V[t]])/Cd[V[t]], j'[t] == (V0[t] - Rt*j[t] - V[t])/L};
bc = {V[0] == A, j[0] == 0 (*, \[Theta][0] == 0*)};
pl = NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, j, {t, 0, 1}]
```

With the OP's definition of `Cd`, we get

> `Power::infy`: Infinite expression `1/0` encountered. >>
>
> `NDSolve::nlnum`: The function value `{31.85,ComplexInfinity}` is not a list of numbers with dimensions `{2}` at `` {t,j[t],V[t],NDSolve`s$50801[t],NDSolve`s$50800[t]} = {0.00612563,-0.000795134,0.,1,1} ``. >>

Here's how I thought about debugging this one:  One should look carefully at the data, which luckily has not been `Short`-ened:

```
{t, j[t], V[t], NDSolve`s$50801[t], NDSolve`s$50800[t]} =
 {0.0061256268269912675`, -0.0007951340768516366`, 0.`, 1, 1}
```

It seems interesting that a time `t = 0.0061256268269912675`, the variable `V[t]` is exactly `0.`.  Two more messages report the same thing at succeeding times, `t = 0.00621476` and `t = 0.00624896`.  But why should `V[t] = 0.`, be of importance?  The original equations do not divide by `V[t]`.

```
eqn
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ah, we see two things. First, there is a discontinuity at `V[t] == 0`, so `NDSolve` will solve for the event where `V[t] == 0`. Second, we do divide by the `Piecewise` function, which has a `0` in it.  And the error was `1/0`, not `1/0.`.  That must be it.  And it was.  (But I'm afraid I don't why the `0` leaked out.  Evaluating `eqn` by hand does not yield an error:

```
eqn /. Thread[{t, j[t], V[t], NDSolve`s$50801[t], NDSolve`s$50800[t]} ->
          {0.0061256268269912675`, -0.0007951340768516366`, 0.`, 1, 1}]
(*
  {Derivative[1][V][0.00612563] == -22718.1, 
   Derivative[1][j][0.00612563] == 31.85}
*)
```

Maybe it's a bug somewhere in the event handling of the discontinuity processing of `NDSolve`.

If we solve either version, the OP's or mine,

```
plOP = NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, {j, V}, {t, 0, 0.01}]
pl = NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, {j, V}, {t, 0, 0.01}]
plOP === pl
(*  True  *)
```

(sorry but be sure to change the `Cd` and `eqn`), we get identical solutions even though the OP's generate `1/0` errors, which are normally catastrophic.  We can see that `V[t]` hit `0.` around `t == 0.006` and then starts to "chatter."  Whether or not it makes physical sense, probably the integration should stop there.  (If it does not make physical sense, then perhaps the model needs tweaking.)

```
Plot @@ {V[t] /. First@pl, Flatten[{t, V["Domain"] /. pl}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can stop the integration when `V[t] == 0` with `WhenEvent`.  Note here if you comment out `Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}`, we get the `1/0` errors, if you use the OP's `Cd`.  It definitely seems like bug in `NDSolve`.

```
pl = NDSolve[{eqn, bc, WhenEvent[V[t] == 0, "StopIntegration"]},
 {j, V}, {t, 0, 0.01}, Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]

Plot @@ {V[t] /. First@pl, Flatten[{t, V["Domain"] /. pl}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Actually that chatter is what I'm most interested in. I'll be doing a further analysis on it to see if I can obtain bifunctional or chaotic behavior by varying `A` and `ω`. I'll look this over carefully and see if I can streamline the output. The starting value of `V[0]` was purely a guess at what the amplitude would be, and figured it wouldn't matter after a short amount of time.

Comment: @LeviJohannesHall Interesting. If you are concerned about discriminating between what behavior is due to the model and what is due to numerical truncation & round-off error, using different settings for `WorkingPrecision` sometimes can help sort that out.  (In this example, the chatter seems well-behaved, however.)

Comment: Thank you! This will definitely be of use.

Answer (score 2):

It is a physical phenomenon occurring in a very short time( milliseconds).

```
A = 1;
ϕ = 0.0257275275;
ω = 151.6*10^3;
Cj = 17*10^(-9);
Cs = 35*10^(-9);
Rt = 223.9;
I0 = 5*10^-6;
L = 15*10^-3;
Cd[t_] := Piecewise[{{Cj/Sqrt[1 - A*Cos[ω*t]/ϕ], 
 t < 0}, {Cs*Exp[A*Cos[ω*t]/ϕ], t >= 0}}];

eqn = {V'[t] == (j[t] - I0*(Exp[A*Cos[ω*t]/ω] - 1))/
Cd[t], j'[t] == (A*Cos[ω*t] - Rt*j[t] - V[t])/L};
bc = {V[0] == A, j[0] == 0};
pl = NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, {V, j}, {t, 0, 0.0001}, 
MaxStepFraction -> 0.0001] // Quiet;
```

Plots:

```
Plot[V[t] /. pl, {t, 0, 0.000011}, PlotRange -> Full, 
AxesLabel -> {"t[ \[Mu]s ]", "V"}, 
Ticks -> {{#, 10^6 #} & /@ FindDivisions[{0., 10^-5}, 10],Automatic}]
Plot[V[t] /. pl, {t, 0.000011, 0.0000132}, 
AxesLabel -> {"t[ \[Mu]s ]", "V"}, 
Ticks -> {{#, 10^6 #} & /@ FindDivisions[{0., 10^-4}, 100] // N, 
Automatic}]
Plot[j[t] /. pl, {t, 0, 0.0000149}, PlotRange -> Full, 
AxesLabel -> {"t[ \[Mu]s ]", "j[ m A ]"}, 
Ticks -> {{#, 10^6 #} & /@ FindDivisions[{0., 10^-5}, 5] // 
N, {#, 10^5 #} & /@ FindDivisions[{-10^-4, 10^-4}, 5] // N}]
```

[image]